# Getting realtime user interaction data from android device

Tags: android, debugging, testing, adb

I want to record the user's activity on a particular application in realtime like which button he clicked and everything he interacts with within the app. The android device can have an engineering binary.

The espresso tool records the interactions but, it needs the source code. I couldn't find a solution to this problem. Please suggest if there is an existing tool that can be used.

I don't have source code of the app. I need a generalized solution which will work on any installed application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Google Analytics or Yandex Analytics, it will show the user interaction statistics for on each activity of your app and for each element.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Actually I don't have the source code of the app and moreover, I need a generalized solution which will work on any installed app.

Comment: It seems that such a decision can violate the rights of users and can be used to steal user data, which is not correct

Comment: I understand but, I'm using an engineering binary device which is not for commercial purpose. So, it won't hurt the user's privacy [because there won't be any real user].